# Determine whether user has various premium features

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried various similar solutions to this which I have found online, but so far nothing seems to quite fit what I need.

Given the following tables, greatly simplified for the purposes of this question:

```
tblRetailers

retailer_id    company_name
---------------------------
1              ABC Ltd
2              DEF Ltd

tblRetailerFeature

retailer_feature_id   retailer_id   feature_option_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1                     1             1
2                     1             4
3                     2             3
4                     2             6

tblFeatureOptions

feature_option_id   feature_id   title     Price
------------------------------------------------
1                   1            30 Days   14.95
2                   1            60 Days   29.90
3                   1            90 Days   44.85
4                   2            30 Days   19.95
5                   2            60 Days   39.90
6                   2            90 Days   59.95

tblFeatures

feature_id   title   
----------------------------
1            Top Listing
2            Gallery Listing
3            Premium Listing
```

I need to determine, for each retailer, whether they have "Top", "Gallery" and/or "Premium" listings

So, the end result should look something like this:

```
retailer_id   hasTopListing   hasGalleryListing   hasPremiumListing
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1             0               1                   0
2             1               1                   0
```

With 0/1 being boolean.
How would the SQL be written for this?

Comment: And what is `Top`, `Gallery` and `Premium` listings?

Comment: Why does `retailer_id` has premium listing?

Comment: Retailers list their businesses for free, but can opt to purchase premium features: Top, Gallery or Premium listings

Comment: `feature_id` = 3 is Premium Listing. Why does `retailer_id` = `2` has premium listing?

Comment: Well-spotted, fixed that for the sake of clarity, though that table was just to show how I want the query result to look, rather than being an actual representation of the data.

Comment: Can you imagine how confusing that is for the rest of us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your schema works, since I can't explain the output you expected from the input you provided.

Nevertheless, this might help:

```
SELECT
  r.retailer_id,
  MAX(fo.feature_id = 1) AS hasTopListing,
  MAX(fo.feature_id = 2) AS hasGalleryListing,
  MAX(fo.feature_id = 3) AS hasPremiumListing
FROM         tblFeatureOptions fo
  INNER JOIN tblRetailerFeature rf
          ON rf.feature_option_id = fo.feature_option_id
  RIGHT JOIN tblRetailers r
          ON r.retailer_id = rf.retailer_id
GROUP BY r.retailer_id
```

Also available on your sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca9f8/10

I assumed that you join `tblRetailerFeature` to `tblFeatureOptions` using the `feature_option_id`. I then simply check whether any of the lines for a given retailer id mentions each of the relevant feature ids. MySQL treats a comparison as a 0/1 value already, so the `MAX` here corresponds to an `OR` over all the rows.

As you can tell from the fiddle, the output is not what you asked for, but it is what I'd expect from your input. So either point out how your data is to be joined, or tweak this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is your solution: [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1773/10)

```
SELECT r.retailer_id,
       IF(rf_1.feature_option_id > 0, 1, 0) AS hasTopListing,
       IF(rf_2.feature_option_id > 0, 1, 0) AS hasGalleryListing,
       IF(rf_3.feature_option_id > 0, 1, 0) AS hasPremiumListing
FROM tblRetailers r
LEFT JOIN tblRetailerFeature rf_1 ON r.retailer_id = rf_1.retailer_id
AND rf_1.feature_option_id IN
  ( SELECT feature_option_id
   FROM tblFeatureOptions
   WHERE feature_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN tblRetailerFeature rf_2 ON r.retailer_id = rf_2.retailer_id
AND rf_2.feature_option_id IN
  ( SELECT feature_option_id
   FROM tblFeatureOptions
   WHERE feature_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN tblRetailerFeature rf_3 ON r.retailer_id = rf_3.retailer_id
AND rf_3.feature_option_id IN
  ( SELECT feature_option_id
   FROM tblFeatureOptions
   WHERE feature_id = 3)
```

Result:

```
RETAILER_ID HASTOPLISTING   HASGALLERYLISTING   HASPREMIUMLISTING
1   1   1   0
2   1   1   0
```